# Notify user when onclick is successful - SmtpClient - when mail is sent

Tags: c#, asp.net, notifications, smtpclient

How do i notify the user that the mail is sent? I searched and found notify.js but I couldn't use it. I didn't know how.

I simply want to popup a message "mail sent" when user clicks the send button in the form I have in my webpage.

This is the button I use:

```
<asp:Button Text="Send" OnClick="sendMail" CssClass="button" runat="server" 
    ID="btn" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="contactUs" />
```

On C# I am using the `SmtpClient` client approach, and it sends successfully.
`SendMail` is the C# class I am using. I want to use a simple approach, is there a notification from C#, or Javascript that is simple?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [register some script to run at startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx). An ugly approach is to just use a JavaScript alert.

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),
    "success_script",
    "alert('Email sent!');",
    true
);
```

A prettier approach would be to use a nice client side notification library. I like [noty](http://ned.im/noty/). You need to add a reference to jQuery followed by a reference to the noty script to your page. Then you can use:

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),
   "success_script",
   "noty({text: 'Email sent!', type: 'success'});",
    true
);
```

Comment: Thank you Mason for the info. Can you please elaborate the place I should put this C# code in, in the .cs file ? should it be in the try{} part after the _onClick_SendMail function ? and how can I put another notification in the catch part ?

Comment: Also Can you elaborate how can I link js noty inside the c#

Comment: Finally, Please explain the step "register some script to run at start up. do you mean I add 
public void RegisterStartupScript(
 Type type,
 string key,
 string script,
 bool addScriptTags
)

Comment: @Sherbieny I don't know where your `try` block is. The code should go wherever you want the notification to be created from. To put another notification, you copy and paste the code I've shown with another notification. And no, I don't mean to add a `public void RegisterStartupScript()` as that method is already part of the `ClientScriptManager` class that I've shown.

Comment: When you say register some script to run at startup, do I need to add something like this in the ASP page: `<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" 
    runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />`

Comment: @Sherbieny I don't think that's necessary, but it can't hurt. By "register some script to run at startup" I mean call `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`.

Comment: How Can I call ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() ? I get errors where ever I put it in cs page

Comment: @Sherbieny Did you look at my code? Did you try it? Where did you put it in your code? What errors are you getting? I can't tell you what you did wrong unless you give me that information.

Comment: I entered your code in the `try` block after my `client.send(msg);` that is fired after the user click send button

Comment: So the Try Block is: `try
        {
        client.Send(msg);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(),
           "success_script",
           "noty({text: 'Email sent!', type: 'success'});",
            true
        );
         
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }`

Comment: What should I add in the page load ? or anywhere else

Comment: @Sherbieny You don't need to add anything in `Page_Load`. You just need the call to RegisterStartupScript to be after you've sent the email. But don't use the `noty version of my code, that's only if you install noty scripts in your application. Get the plain `alert` based code working first, then you can think about using noty.

Comment: Can you write the RegisterStartupScript part please. Also what do you mean by installing noty scripts, I have downloaded Noty and added it to the project and linked it on the ASP file

Comment: @Sherbieny Did you *read* my answer? It clearly shows the code for `RegisterStartupScript`.

Comment: I am sorry for being a pain :) I am not very familiar with js. when I added your answer in the try block and installed the noty nothing happened. please explain what should I do

Comment: Update your question to include your latest code (leave the old code intact). Check your browser's JavaScript console for errors. Also, *don't use the noty example* until you've got the basic `alert()` working. You don't need to get fancy until you've figured out the basics.